# Использование IF в Hibernate (HQL)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, sql

```
String q = "SELECT id, name, " +
                "IF (ABS(name) > 0, LPAD(ABS(name), 4, '0'), name) AS tord " +
                "FROM table where city= " + cityId + " order by tord";

    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(q);
    List<Object[]> list = query.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

Хочу этот кусок отрефакторить с помощью HQL, но как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте CASE

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456181/using-a-case-statement-in-hql-select